# Can one use sql query in default.aspx web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, t-sql

Can I use sql query and alter server url based on the sql query result?

If sql query gives value of 1, point the server to home.aspx and if the sql query gives value of 0, point to home2.aspx?

I am trying to show different person different homepage based on a specific associated value in sql database.

Thank you

p.s. I honestly dont know how the log in works. I am not a .net guy and didn't create the system. I know about URL direct for the server in default.aspx because I have been through that. there is singlesignon settings applied on the website so when a user logs into the lets say web A, he/she can click on a hyperlink, it will pass the encrypted user login info and the user will automatically be on the home page of website b (log in page for website B is skipped). I will update my acceptance rate.

Thank you

p.s. 2: I am just trying to pull the INCOMING user's active flag from a column in a table in a sql db. If the flag for that particular user is set to 1, point them to URL A, if flag is set to 0, point them to URL B.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect doing that but **you should not**! Why? Well, calling the DB every time a visitor comes will make your response time way long to wait. What you can do is cache the result on memory or at least disk (using a B+ tree for example) or better to provide a common homepage and then redirect.

Now, once you identify a user set say a cookie for the redirection and for so on use the cookie (don't forget it to authorize if needed), that'll speed up things.

Go ahead and take a look to [personalization and user profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163724.aspx) on ASP.NET which is what you want to do.

Comment: Well, a user would loginto website A and they will click on a hyperlink on that website and they will be automatically logged into Webside B and will land on the homepage. if I provide a common homepage and redirect, will they be able to login automatically like they do now?

Comment: Sure, for that you store the redirect address on a cookie the first time, next time you look on that instead of DB. Will be way more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Randolf's comments are true. But in order to do what you want, if you for some reason still want to do this, you'll want to look at Server.Transfer() (more efficient, and preferable if you are redirecting to another page that's on the same server, within the same app), or Response.Redirect().

Comment: You mean I can use Server.Transfer() if I want to use DB query?

Comment: Where you get the data to make the decision is separate from how you redirect.  Server.Transfer() is kind of a server side redirect.

Comment: You can use Server.Transfer() wherever you want, it doesn't mean it's a good idea. I think you can probably get it working the brute force way as you originally intended. Do the db lookup, and use Server.Transfer() to redirect to the correct page based on the db lookup results.  THEN, when that works, look at the optimizations that randolf suggested.

Comment: Humm, will give this a try and see how long it takes.